# Does the ASUS P8Z77-V DELUXE support WOL

Tags: wake-on-lan

Does anyone know if the ASUS P8Z77-V DELUXE supports Wake On LAN, and if so, how I can enable it?  I can't seem to find an option to do so in the BIOS, but I'm hoping I'm overlooking something

Comment: Check BIOS option `Power On By PCIE` in Advanced \ APM.

Comment: Your specifications say it does, down near the bottom of this page in the Bios section>>>>https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z77V_DELUXE/specifications/

Comment: Your manual>>>>>https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z77V_DELUXE/HelpDesk_Manual/

Comment: @Nassbirne If you make your comment an answer I will accept it as that did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIOSes usually have an option like

`Power On By PCIE` (or `Power On By PCI` on older boards)

located in `Advanced` -> `APM` (or a similar submenu that contains power-related options).

For WOL, this option must be enabled.